# single quote inside double quote in php

Tags: php

```
<input id="myID" onClick="CheckAll('A','B');" />
```

In the project,the above code need to be put into String(see 2nd snippet). However, the CheckAll() is already inside the single quote. If two parameters are inside Single quote in checkAll() like 2nd code snippet, the checkAll() won't work.

How to fix the 2nd code snippet?

Thanks in advance and any help will be really appreciated!

```
$string ="<input id='myID' onClick='CheckAll('A','B');' />"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use backslash:

```
$string ="<input id=\"myID\" onClick=\"CheckAll('A','B');\" />"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string ="<input id='myID' onClick=\"CheckAll('A','B');\" />"
```

add escaping slashes

Comment: Actually, that won't work - the escaped quotes need to be double quotes, so that when it gets output, it's not single quotes inside more single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively

```
$string = '<input id="myID" onClick="CheckAll(\'A\',\'B\');" />';
```